Plane is pink in shading mode
I was making a donut and went to the Shading workspace to apply random colors to the sprinkles. I did not do any work and went off after saving the blend file. Now when I reopen the blend file, I see my plane texture is gone and turned pink and there is somewhat a 3D world in the background.
How do I make it look like before, like in the video?



That colour means that the texture file is missing so presumably you've moved it since saving the blend file. the '3D world' in the background is the built-in HDRI which lights the scene in Material Preview mode .
